# Struggling to create MySQL Connection Pool on Glassfish

Tags: mysql, glassfish, connection-pooling

I've done this before but for some reason I'm really having some difficulty creating this connection pool. When I ping the connection pool after creating it I get this error:

```
Ping Connection Pool for bondsaver is Failed. 
Ping failed Exception - Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for : com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource 
    Please check the server.log for more details. 
Ping failed Exception - Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for : com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource 
    Please check the server.log for more details.
```

The info I've provided in the creation of the pool is as follows:

- `portNumber`: 3306;
- `databaseName`: bondsaverdb;
- `serverName`: localhost;
- `user`: root;
- `password`: mypassword;

Is there anything I've left out? Anything I misspelled or inputted incorrectly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to be a classpath issue. Do you have the mysql connector in your domain's lib dir?

The correct path should be:

> *glassfish-install-dir*\glassfish\domains\domain1\lib

(or a different domain name if you don't use the default *domain1*)

Comment: Ahh. Damit. I did have the connector yes, but little did I know I was putting the connector in the wrong glassfish instance that I have on my machine. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction Matt. Much appreciated!